# Usar ou não usar barra no final de uma URL?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Sempre que eu vou criar um novo site e pensar no `.htaccess` me bate aquela dúvida: forçar ou não forçar o uso de barra no final da URL.

Por exemplo:
http://meusite.com seria 301-redirecionado para http://meusite.com/.

Fazendo esse  redirecionamento, o tempo de  carregamento pode demorar um pouco mais, pouco eu sei, mas cada bit conta num site de grandes proporções.

Não adicionando a barra final, porém, pode ocasionar conteúdo duplicado nas listagens do Google, e prejudicar o SEO do site.

Então,  definitivamente, deve-se ou não usar a barra no final de uma URL? E quais as principais razões?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o `rel="canonical"`, fica a seu critério. Exemplo:

Insiro ele no head da página, com o nome da página original no "href":

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.exemplo.com.br" />
```

Aí o google vai ler, e se o conteúdo for igual, ele vai jogar todo o ranking na url que está no href, então nestas páginas abaixo eu tenho o rel="canonical" direcionado ao `http://www.exemplo.com.br`:

- `http://exemplo.com.br`
- `http://www.exemplo.com.br`
- `http://www.exemplo.com.br/`
- `http://www.exemplo.com.br/index.html`

Comment: Interessante! Acho que isso é bom ser utilizado de uma forma ou outra, mesmo com ou sem a barra no final.

Answer (score 4):

A ideia de que fazer um redirect 301 causa perda de pagerank é um [mito](http://searchengineland.com/google-pagerank-dilution-through-a-301-redirect-is-a-myth-149656), e você não tem com o que se preocupar. Qualquer resposta além disso vai ser provavelmente uma questão de opinião pessoal. Desde que as suas urls sirvam o mesmo conteúdo, [tanto faz ter ou não a barra no final](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html).

Comment: +1 pelo tanto faz.

Answer (score 2):

Tratando-se da URL principal do domínio, acho desnecessário colocar a barra no final, uma vez que alguns navegadores como o Chrome já removem a barra automaticamente da barra de endereços:
Veja o comportamento ao digitar no barra de endereços do Chrome:

> `http://localhost/`

é automaticamente simplificado para

> `localhost`

Porém existe uma ressalva quanto ao sistema que estiver rodando do lado do servidor, que pode interpretar de maneiras diferente a URL solicitada. 
Por exemplo um sistema pode estar usando a URL e separando as barras para algum uso interno.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php print_r(explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) ?>
```

> `http://localhost/index.php/modulo/`

Imprimirá um primeiro ítem 'modulo' e um segundo ítem vazio

> `http://localhost/index.php/modulo`

Imprimirá somente um primeiro ítem 'modulo'.

Ou seja, por conta de SEO não acho necessário, a nível sistêmico depende de cada caso.